# I get kicked out of session when trying to send a api request | Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, session

When i login into my Laravel application and dont click the checkbox "Remember me" then i will get kicked out of my session everytime when i try to make a api request but i don't know why.
If i click the checkbox "Remember me" everthing works fine.

Here is my session config:

```
    'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),



    'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 120),

    'expire_on_close' => false,



    'encrypt' => false,


    'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),



    'connection' => env('SESSION_CONNECTION', null),


    'table' => 'sessions',



    'store' => env('SESSION_STORE', null),



    'lottery' => [2, 100],

  

    'cookie' => env(
        'SESSION_COOKIE',
        Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_session'
    ),



    'path' => '/',



    'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),



    'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE'),


    'http_only' => true,


    'same_site' => 'lax',
```

In my .env:

```
SESSION_DRIVER=redis
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
```

I can't find the error.

Any ideas?

Comment: what do you mean by API request. as remember me is working for HTTP requests and the session is stateless in API requests.

Comment: the user is stored in the session and when i make an api call i ask if the user has the appropriate permission. But because I get kicked out of the session every time Auth::user = null so I get an error.